# Show an ngMessage if ngOptions array is empty

Tags: html, angularjs

Is it possible to use `ngMessages` to show an error while initializing options of a `select` element using `ngOptions`?
For ex. in

```
<select name="fruitNames" ng-model="fruitName" ng-options="fruit.name for fruit in fruits"></select>
```

if `fruits` is empty, I want to show an error message.

Comment: `<div class="error" ng-show="!fruits">No fruits!!! :o!!</div>`

Comment: Thought of doing like this myself, but my final objective is more complicated than this example. I wanted to learn if it is possible with `ngMessages`, as most of the examples online use it only with `form` element. Found the solution, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could provide any expression to `ng-messages` as a kvp, example i am setting boolean value to `hasFruits` and using the key `hasFruits`.

```
<div ng-messages="{noFruits:!fruits.length}" >
    <div ng-message="noFruits">Sorry, No fruits available!!</div>
  </div>
```

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.fruits = [];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-messages.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-messages="{hasFruits:!fruits.length}">
    <div ng-message="hasFruits">No fruits available!!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This however seems a bit weird since you really don't have multiple conditions here (Unlike the way you use ngMessages with $error object), you could just show and hide a div as well instead.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for. However, could you please elaborate how can I define multiple conditions?

Comment: My objective is a little complicated, but I think I can manage it now. Just want to know if it is possible to do something like `ng-messages="{string1:condition}{string2:condition}..."`

Comment: @yoogeeks Yes right as long as the condition is true that particular ng-message directive will show.

Comment: Thanks, got final solution with `ng-messages="{string1:condition1, string2:condition2}"`